# Where can I find open source LP solvers?

Tags: linear-programming, solver, online-resources, open-source

I'm familiar with [COIN-OR](https://www.coin-or.org/) and have also used a couple packages in R to solve LPs. Today I found out Google has their own [open source optimization software](https://developers.google.com/optimization/), and it got me wondering what other open source LP solvers are out there?

Comment: Some of that Gookel-listed OR-Tools software is actually COIN-OR, not Google-developed. For instance, the MILIP solver, CBC https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification since I hadn't had a chance to dig in to it yet.

Comment: I think this is the type of question that would do well if answered as a community wiki

Comment: Maybe I am too picky, but besides the tag, the question and the titel do not mention what you want to solve. A reader might think you are searching for a MDP solver or something else.

Comment: Fair point. I'll add that clarification to my post.

Comment: Are you looking for a simplex solver for LP, or an interior point solver? Or are you just looking for something that will solve LPs?

Comment: Typically I'm just looking for "something that will give me the optimal solution with as few drawbacks as possible." However, an answer that explains why I should be more picky would be helpful.

Comment: I agree this question is too broad, but if you can be more specific about what you are looking on, I will probably vote to reopen. For example, are you looking for an LP solver? A MIP solver? Something more general? Specifically open-source? Something specifically for R?

Comment: We settled on specifically open source and specifically LP solvers (which is most of what I use as a freelancer who doesn't want to pay licensing fees).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[OpenSolver](https://opensolver.org/) is an LP/IP/NLP solver that plugs into Microsoft Excel. I used it for some classroom stuff a while back and was quite pleased with it.

If you are interested in metaheuristics, there are quite a few open-source contributions floating around (about which I mostly know nothing). I have used the [Watchmaker Framework for Evolutionary Computation](https://watchmaker.uncommons.org/) (i.e., genetic algorithms) successfully in a couple of projects. I don't think it is under active development any more (although the developer might respond to pull requests), but it is quite well documented and works. Not long ago, I looked around and found some other Java-based GA libraries, but have not gotten around to testing any.

Answer (score 19):

[Mittelmann](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp.html) benchmarks a number of (LP-)Solvers, some of which are open source. A recent new open source solver is [HiGHS](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS).

Answer (score 16):

I compiled [a list](https://github.com/eltuck/Resources#math-programming-software) of solvers I could find last year. Several are COIN-OR-affiliated, but others include Mini-CP, DSP, BiqBin, OSQP, ECOS, and Dakota. (Edit - not all are dedicated LP, see comments below)

Comment: Few of these are (dedicated) LP solvers, so will lack the ability to exploit the form and sparsity of practical LP problems in order to compete with specialist solvers.

Comment: Thanks for this comment - this will surely be helpful for others. As a note, the original version of the question wasn’t specifically about LPs.

Answer (score 12):

I believe SCIP is the fastest non-commercial solver. It’s free for academic use. You can check out the benchmarks by Hans Mittelmann for other suggestions.

Comment: Is it open source?

Comment: Yes but only for academic use.

Comment: Where can we find the source? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest starting on their [website](https://scip.zib.de/)

Comment: Yes it is open-source [link](https://scip.zib.de/index.php#download)

Comment: @DavidBernal many thanks!!

Comment: It is technically not open-source. You can download the source code and look at it, but you can only use it for academic purposes unless you acquire a commercial license.

Comment: SCIP is a MIP solver. Although it can be used to solve LPs, the default open-source LP solver it uses is Soplex which, although reliable is far from being the fastest open-source LP solver. In all this I'm referring to simplex solvers.

Comment: The question didn't originally ask for LP solvers. See the edits :)

Answer (score 10):

Just to add another, easily google-able, resource: Wikipedia, more or less, "maintains" a ["List of optimization software"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software) -- which includes the *super handy* ["Mathematical optimization software"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Mathematical_optimization_software) template I -- disclaimer: shameless self-plug -- started 6 years ago (and never bothered to curate) [the latter also includes references to alternat(iv)e taxonomies in its ["talk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_talk:Mathematical_optimization_software) section].

Comment: This WIkipedia page doesn't (really) mention COIN-OR, or widely-used high quality open-source solvers such as CBC or CLP. It really needs updating

Comment: @SparseRunner Well, it's Wikipedia... so you _can_ add relevant information when/if it's missing. (The template includes references to CBC, CLP, and other COIN-OR projects.)

Answer (score 5):

Another open-source software is the [GNU Linear Programming Kit (GLPK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Linear_Programming_Kit) and can be downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/).

Description (from Wikipedia):

> The GNU Linear Programming Kit is a software package intended for solving large-scale linear programming, mixed integer programming, and other related problems. It is a set of routines written in ANSI C and organized in the form of a callable library.

Comment: As a simplex solver, Mittelmann's benchmarks show GLPK to be terribly slow for large-scale LPs