# Open source Markov decision process solvers

Tags: markov-decision-process, online-resources

Which sources are out there that provide reliable and fast MDP solvers? I prefer that the library is callable from C++ but other languages are fine too.

There is indeed an abundance of repositories on github that at first seem to be appropriate for this task. However, the ones I found so far were either buggy, super slow, or overly optimized for a too specific model (such as all my own implementations).

This question is similar as the question
[open source LP solvers](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/4) but now for MDP solvers.

Answer (score 6):

You could try MDPtoolbox from [here](http://www7.inra.fr/mia/T/MDPtoolbox/Install.html) in which the package is ready to download for Matlab, R, and Python. The functions prepared in a manner that any user can easily modify it for specific problem instances.